# $PATH corruption on Cygwin on Windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, path

I am running cygwin on a Windows 10 computer. If I execute $PATH from the cygwin command window, I get the following error:

```
$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

My suspicion is that the error is associated with trying to create either `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`. I am familiar with the necessity of preceding the blank with `\` when typing Windows path names on Cygwin. However, I have checked my `.bashrc` file and there are no entries of `Program Files`. I think the Cygwin install must have automatically created this path entry but somehow it got corrupted. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The value of `$PATH` is not meant to be executed. `No such file or directory` is totally expected when you try to execute `$PATH`. Trying to execute `$PATH` makes no sense. What are you really trying to do? `echo $PATH` makes sense. `echo "$PATH"` makes even more sense.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski and `( IFS=:; printf "%s\n" $PATH )` makes even more

Answer (score 2):

The `$PATH` is a variable that contains a colon-separated list of directories (folders) that are searched for commands to execute. For example, if you enter `ls` and you get a successful result it's been found in one of the directories listed in `$PATH`<sup>*</sup>.

Here's a segment of my `$PATH`, using the `echo` command to display it

```
echo "$PATH"

/cygdrive/C/Users/roaima/OneDrive - Contoso/Documents/bin:/usr/local/my/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Local/bin:/cygdrive/c/Local/Apps/yt-dlp_win:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk1.8.0_222/bin:…:/cygdrive/c/Users/roaima/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Nmap:/cygdrive/c/Users/roaima/.dotnet/tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/SMPlayer/mpv:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/SMPlayer/mplayer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Sophos/Sophos SSL VPN Client/bin
```

Even with a large chunk removed from the middle (`…`) it's still a very long list. You can tidy it up somewhat by using `printf` and having it output one element per line:

```
( IFS=:; printf "%s\n" $PATH )

/cygdrive/C/Users/roaima/OneDrive - Contoso/Documents/bin
/usr/local/my/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
…
```

Now, to explain what happened when you tried to execute `$PATH`. The shell split the line at whitespace (spaces), looked for the first part to execute, with the remainder of the items as parameters to that command. In my case the first space is just after the word `OneDrive` so my "command" would be `/cygdrive/C/Users/roaima/OneDrive`, which isn't a command that can be executed:

```
$PATH
-bash: /cygdrive/C/Users/roaima/OneDrive: Is a directory
```

Conclusion? Don't try to execute `$PATH` - it's not a command to be executed.

Next part. You write, "*I am familiar with the necessity of preceding the blank with \ when typing Windows path names on Cygwin*" - If the commands are in a directory listed in `$PATH` you can just run them by name, without specifying the directory. For example, I can directly run `notepad` and it will just work. You can also quote strings that contain spaces, so

```
'/cygdrive/c/local programs/notepad++' myfile.txt
```

But if that directory was in my `$PATH` I could also just run this:

```
notepad++ myfile.txt
```

---

<sup>* Or it's an alias or a function, but let's ignore those for now</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To get to grips with what `$PATH` is and how you can 'use' it...

`$ man bash` will display the man(ual) page for Bash...
With it up you have `less` running, i.e. hitting <kbd>h</kbd> will tell you what keys to press to get certain functions -  <kbd>q</kbd> quits the help.

<kbd>/</kbd> will initiate a (regexp) search, which means that typing
`/^ +PATH` <kbd>Enter</kbd> will lookup the title for `$PATH` - so that you can get informed.

Further, [tdlp.org](https://tldp.org/) has two `Bash guides` - they are hands on and very informative still, though being slightly old.